# R: Create Integer Array from Two Columns, then Plot Histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 2 numeric columns.  For each row, I want to create an array of integers that fall between the values in the columns, and that includes the values in the column.  Then, I want to compile all of the values into a single column to generate a histogram.

Input:

```
df
    C1    C2
A   3   -92
B   8   -162
C   20  -97
D   50  -76
```

Output:

```
sdf5$Values
-92
-91
-90
...
2
3
-162
-161
...
7
8
...
```

My actual dataframe has 62 rows.  My current code gives me frequencies > 100 (should have a maximum of 62 for any integer).  The code worked on a dummy dataframe, so I'm not sure where things are going wrong.

```
list <- mapply(":", df$C2, df$C1)
df3 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, list)
sdf3 <- stack(df3)
sdf4 <- as.data.frame(sdf3$values)
sdf5 <- rename(sdf4, Values = 1)

a <- ggplot(sdf5, aes(x=Values)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, center=0)
```

Comment: Can you show an example that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something off going on with the `stack` function, you can check it using `table`. To put all list numbers into a single vector I'd use `unlist`.

```
df=data.frame(C1=floor(runif(80,0,200)),C2=floor(runif(80,-200,0)))
list <- mapply(":", df$C2, df$C1)
df3 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, list)
sdf3 <- stack(df3)
sdf4 <- data.frame("Values"=sdf3$values)

table(sdf4) 
# This returns the count of each unique value and some go up to 200, 
# notably the limits of my unif distribution
```

If you use `unlist`, it gives the desired result.

```
df=data.frame(C1=floor(runif(80,0,200)),C2=floor(runif(80,-200,0)))
list <- mapply(":", df$C2, df$C1)
vec <- data.frame("Values"=unlist(list))

a <- ggplot(vec, aes(x=Values)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, center=0)
```

I don't know the stack function, but the problem must be there somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly goes wrong, but I think the `rbind.data.frame` is causing some troubles with the list input. As an alternative:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(text = "    C1    C2
A   3   -92
B   8   -162
C   20  -97
D   50  -76")

list <- mapply(":", df$C2, df$C1)
df2 <- data.frame(Values = do.call(c, list))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=Values)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, center=0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>